# Flutter: Get the local position from the GestureDetector

Tags: flutter

I'm using the GestureDetector to get this events using:

```
onHorizontalDragStart: _onDragStart,
onHorizontalDragUpdate: _onDragUpdate,
```

But how can I transform the global position into local? The child that is moved is a Container.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use a `RenderObject` and then transform the global positions into a local one similar to this simple example:

```
import "package:flutter/material.dart";

class Test extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TestState createState() => new _TestState();
}

class _TestState extends State<Test> {
  _onDragStart(BuildContext context, DragStartDetails start) {
    print(start.globalPosition.toString());
    RenderBox getBox = context.findRenderObject();
    var local = getBox.globalToLocal(start.globalPosition);
    print(local.dx.toString() + "|" + local.dy.toString());
  }

  _onDragUpdate(BuildContext context, DragUpdateDetails update) {
    //print(update.globalPosition.toString());
    RenderBox getBox = context.findRenderObject();
    var local = getBox.globalToLocal(update.globalPosition);
    //print(local.dx.toString() + "|" + local.dy.toString());
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      body: new Center(
        child: new GestureDetector(
          child: new Text("Drag"),
          onHorizontalDragStart: (DragStartDetails start) =>
              _onDragStart(context, start),
          onHorizontalDragUpdate: (DragUpdateDetails update) =>
              _onDragUpdate(context, update),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: perfect RenderBox getBox = context.findRenderObject();

Comment: bear in mind that this will _not_ work during the build method. If you ever wonder how to do a similar thing during build, you can use `LayoutBuilder`.

Comment: Yes, the findRenderObject is valid only after layout phase. Thanks again.

Comment: What is the difference between this approach, and using the `DragStartDetails.localPosition`?

Comment: @PeterBruins global approach gives position from context start and `DragStartDetails.localPosition` gives position from DragStart point