# How do I detect a swipe gesture from widget edge to center of widget

Tags: flutter

I would like to know how to detect a gesture swipe starting from one of the edges of the widget going down towards the center?

Edit:
I have tried to use the Gesturedetector. There is a lot of information comming from the GestureDetector and I am unable to filter out the correct information.

Comment: Use GestureDetector class.

Comment: Yes, I know. But how do I setup the Gesturedetector. There is a lot of information comming from the GestureDetector and I am unable to filter out the correct information.

Comment: Check those Links: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52000130/flutter-get-local-position-of-gesture-detector/52010990) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47272323/flutter-get-the-local-position-from-the-gesturedetector)

Comment: Thanks. Lot of good reading.

Comment: Next step. My Scaffold have 3 widgets. I it possible to use GestureDetect indiviually on each of those widgets ??

Comment: Not sure how your widget layout looks like, But i thinks it's possible.